# SSO login between React SPA and directus app using directus credentials

Tags: single-sign-on, directus

I need help. I have react SPA application which using directus as backend and we are also using directus login credentials to login in react SPA. Now I need whenever I am logged into the spa and opening the directus url in a new tab it should auto login and not ask me login again because I am already logged into my SPA.
Directus app is self hosted and version is 9.21.2
Please help me with solution

Need solution on this

Comment: did you find a solution for this?